# Is there any command to list all related files and folders to specified file in macosx?

Tags: command-line, osx, command

I have many ctags in my macosx. When doing `which ctags`, it gave me `/usr/bin/ctags`.

But I also want to know where is all related folders and files to this `/usr/bin/ctags`

Any useful command?

Comment: How would you define "related"?

Comment: Its library files and folders or anything that coming with it when first installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can view all application dependancies for a file with `otool` in Mac OS X. Here is an excerpt from the `otool` man page:

> The  otool  command  displays  specified parts of object files or libraries.

For your specific need the following should work:

```
otool -L $(which ctags)
```

For additional files see [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029410/how-to-detect-files-related-to-an-app-on-a-mac) on where to look for other application related files